# Bootsrap3 row columns gutter collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to collapse the columns in Twitter Bootstrap3 ?

For removing the columns gutter padding we can use the following in Zurb Foundation:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
</div>
```

How can this be achieved in Twitter Bootstrap ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to override the CSS..

```
.row [class*="-6"] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Or, create a special class.

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

.no-gutter [class*="-6"] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/73960

Or, customize your Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: OK, so theres no Bootstrap default for collapsing columns

This is the solution for Bootstrap3:

    .no-gutter [class^="col-"] {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way:

```
.no-gutter {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;    
}

.no-gutter > [class^="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```